# Unable to load extension: compass-susy

Tags: rubygems, sass, susy-compass, susy

I've attempted to install Compass, which initially seemed successful, but when checking the version I see this:

```
compass --version
Unable to load extension: compass-susy
```

I'm not sure exactly what this notice means - so that is my first question.

I installed Susy separately too but I still see the notice above. Assuming this is something I need to resolve, what would be the steps to do so.

Comment: Do you know what version of Compass installed?

Comment: Do the other Compass commands work (`compass create`, `compass watch`, etc?)?

Comment: Yep they work fine!
Do you know what 'Unable to load extension: compass-susy' means exactly?

Comment: You've installed the latest version of Susy as well?  [There are similar issues on the repo](https://github.com/Compass/compass/search?q=Unable+to+load+extension&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93), but each case indicates that installation fails.

Comment: Yup up-to-date
susy (2.1.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no longer any such thing as `compass-susy`. That was the name of Susy before the 1.0 release a few years back. Find any mention of `compass-susy` in your code base and replace it with `susy`.